# Why can't PowerShell load file or assembly to run Azure PowerShell Module?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I can't get PowerShell to run `connect-azaccount`.  When I invoke it (using `connect-azaccount -subscriptionid #######...`) I get:

`connect-azaccount : The 'connect-azaccount' command was found in the module 'Az.Accounts', but the module could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module Az.Accounts'.
At line:1 char:1
+ connect-azaccount -subscriptionid ######### ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (connect-azaccount:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoloadMatchingModule`

Per [this troubleshooting module](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/blob/master/documentation/troubleshoot-module-load.md), the issue could be outdated .NET.  But I updated to the latest version and that didn't resolve the problem.  Same results.

When I run `Import-Module Az.Accounts` I get:

`Import-Module : Could not load file or assembly 'file://\\internal_corp_domain.com\Profiles\my_username\My
Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Az.Accounts\1.8.0\Microsoft.Azure.PowerShell.Authentication.Abstractions.dll' or
one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-Module Az.Accounts
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Import-Module], FileLoadException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatXmlUpdateException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand`

The file path in that last error is puzzling.  It appears to maybe be a network share.  There are many discussions about this online, but nothing appears pertinent except that I might have a blocked file related to NTFS.  Searches for NTFS tell me what it is, but I don't see how to find a block, espec when the path is to a network share I can't access.
Any pointers?

Comment: Can you provide the versions of .NET as well as the version of the AzModule/Az.Accounts Module?

Comment: Also, are you running both the new `Az` as well as the old `AzureRM` PowerShell modules at the same time? You should uninstall the `AzureRM` module and only have the new `Az` module. Run `Get-Module -ListAvailable` to see what Module locations are being used. Also check what module paths are listed via the environment variable: `$env:PSModulePath`

Comment: Could you please try to re-open your powershell with administrator and run the command again ?

Comment: Upgrading from PowerShell 5.1 to  PowerShell 7 solved the issue @HAL9256

Comment: Upgrading from PowerShell 5.1 to PowerShell 7 solved the issue@HuryShen, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading from PowerShell 5.1 to PowerShell 7 solved the issue.